# How do you change the command to lock the screen in kde plasma 5?

Tags: command-line, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I installed xscreensaver in kde, because i dont like the way the default gnome screensaver looks, and after installing xscreensaver, i uninstalled gnome screensaver. I am not asking for the keyboard combo, i need to change the command. Whenever i press lock screen in the application launcher thinking its using the xscreensaver command, it says the screen locker is broken, and i need to use ctrl alt f2 and enter,

> loginctl unlock-sessions

to unlock it, im assuming its using the old gnome screensaver command, because i uninstalled it. Is there anyway to change the lock screen button command to use xscreensaver's command? That is:

> xscreensaver-command -lock

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you I have a direct answer. Replace the contents of /usr/lib/kscreenlocker_greet with the command below and then make the file executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
xscreensaver-command -lock
```

Now clicking the "Lock" button in the launcher will execute the script.

Comment: nice finding! Mine was located here: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet`. I just renamed this one and created the script in your answer to replace it. It's worth mentioning to run the daemon (`xscreensaver -nosplash &`) on startup as a service or as a script in autostart before using it.